# poetogen – Alternativbedeutungen, Herkunft, Herleitung

Tags: meaning, etymology

Über den Begriff ***poetogen*** stolpere ich immer wieder und suche deshalb nach Erklärungen, wie es zu zu diesem kam.
Unter den ersten Google-Treffern ist die [Topik des Sonetts](http://books.google.de/books?id=-TnUmNhQZZUC&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=poetogen&source=bl&ots=gyx47A6RgF&sig=1WryPetq2JN8tE6QvDc7Hctxr-I&hl=de&sa=X&ei=KqpOU9_yCtDXsgbJxYDwCg&ved=0CEcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=poetogen&f=false), die eine Erklärung liefert: *Poetogen* ist etwas, das »in besonderer Weise poesiegeeignet [ist]«.

Ich suche nach dazugehörigen Substantiven, Wortherkunft, Alternativerklärungen, ...

Comment: Ich würde stark vermuten, dass hier eine Analogie zu [fotogen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fotogen), [telegen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/telegen) und [filmogen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/filmogen) besteht.

Answer (score 7):

Ich lebe offenbar in einem anderen Universum als Milla, denn ich bin noch niemals zuvor über das Wort »poetogen« gestolpert.

Man muss Google schon dazu zwingen, dieses Wort als Suchbegriff zu akzeptieren (indem man nämlich ausdrücklich »pathogen« ausschließt), und dann findet man nur zwei Arten von Treffern: Seiten, auf denen steht, dass das gesucht Wort nicht gefunden wurde und Ausschnitte aus Büchern über Literatur.

Ich vermute daher, dass vor rund fünf Jahren ein Literaturkritiker oder ein Literatur-Fachbuchautor diesen Begriff in Analogie zu fotogen usw. erfunden hat (siehe Wrzlprmfts Kommentar auf das Frage-Posting). Und ich vermute weiter, dass andere Autoren, die sich gerne mit ausgefallenen Wörtern schmücken, diesen Begriff recycelt haben.

Comment: Ich lebe im gleichen Universum wie du. Das Wort klingt auch einfach zu abgefahren.

Comment: Es schindet aber erst mal Eindruck, bis man erkennt das es reines Blech ist.

Answer (score 1):

Manche Leute glauben, wenn sie ausgefallene oder selbstgebastelte Fremdwörter benützen, sagen sie etwas Bedeutendes und heben damit ihre Autoritat. Dabei sagen sie eigentlich nichts, es ist nur akademisches Blablabla.

PS Ich lese gerade nochmals diesen Diskurs und die Erklärung von poetogen - was besonders poesiegeeignet ist. Eigentlich müßte man sagen, gerade wenn es poetogen ist, dann muß das Thema so abgedroschen sein, das man kaum noch hinschaut.